# phonegap-plugin-push: ServicePackager package did not load

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I just added phonegap-plugin-push to my barebones phonegap app. When I build and run the application I receive the error message that the ServicePackager package did not load correctly. It throws an error when calling the following:

```
    pushRegistration.on('notification', function (data, d2) {
        alert('Push Received: ' + data.message);
    });
```

The activity log shows the following error:

-

> CreateInstance failed for package [ServicesPackage][Exception has
>   been thrown by the target of an invocation.]:{ at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes) at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstanceFromInternal(String assemblyFile,
>   String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder 
>   binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo) at
>   System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String
>   typeName)}[Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.Contracts.1.5,
>   Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or 
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.]:{ at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.Services.Package.ServicesPackage..ctor()}

I can't make heads or tails out of what its trying to tell me.

Notes:

- I'm following Azure article [Add Push Notifications to your Apache Cordova App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-push/).
- I just recently had VS2015/Cordova issues where some Cordova project system components were failing to load. Clearing and rebuilding the VS MEF cache got everything working again.
- The same application runs perfect on another computer. In fact I copied the entire project folder to another computer and it successfully built and ran without  modifications.

Please help,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I did not have Android Support Library installed which caused the problem. After I installed the Adroid Support Library (run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe" as admin) and selecting "Android Support Libary" from the extra folder the problem went away. See article, ["Add Push Notifications to your Apache Cordova App"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-push/) for a complete list of required SDKs...

Check the box next to each required SDK in the Extras folder that is not installed. The following packages are required:
•   Android Support Library version 23 or greater
•   Android Support Repository version 20 or greater
•   Google Play Services version 27 or greater
•   Google Repository version 22 or greater